# Bash: cannot execute binary file (followed directions from online)

Tags: bash, installation

I am having difficulty installing something, and wanted to write a detailed list of what I did (including all paths, because I am new to Linux, and have problems reading things unless the full path is listed)

1) I am trying to run a program called "**pslToBed**". I downloaded it from here (http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/linux.x86_64/).

2) It downloaded a single file called "pslToBed". It looks like a binary file (all jibberish at least), and I saved to the directory `/Users/MacOwner/Desktop/rnaseq/pslToBed`

3) I did `echo $PATH`, and got the following

```
/usr/local/bin:/Users/MacOwner/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:~/bin:/Users/MacOwner/Desktop/bedtools2-2.19.1
```

4) I selected one path from step (3), namely `/usr/local/bin`

5) I did: `cp /Users/MacOwner/Desktop/rnaseq/pslToBed /usr/local/bin/`

6) I added the same line to the bottom of both **~/.bashrc** and **~./bash_profile**:
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/pslToBed`

Then, I returned to `/Users/MacOwner/Desktop/rnaseq/` and tried to run `pslToBed` but got an error `-bash: /usr/local/bin/pslToBed: cannot execute binary file`

I know this may be straightforward to experienced users, but I am stuck, even after searching the internet for several hours now. Do my paths and ideas look correct? And if not, what should I do to get this program running?

Comment: Are you trying to execute a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: Thank you. I have "Intel Core 2 Duo", which is listed as 64-bit machine (I think). Let me see if I can figure out what binary the file is...

Comment: Try `uname -a` in the console. It should tell you whether your linux version is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: When I do file pslToBed, I get "pslToBed: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped"

Comment: Judging by the x86_64 in the filename, it is 64 bit.

Comment: Doing uname -a leads to: Darwin k55-1.nat.iastate.edu 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Comment: You are not actually running Linux at all. You are running Mac OS X. You can't download an executable file intended for use with Linux and run it on Mac OS X, they're completely different systems.

Comment: Eeep. I'm running Mac OS X. Sorry if I indicated otherwise elsewhere...

Comment: Oh no... Okay, I have access to a server, when I do uname -a, I get: Linux hpc5 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 10:48:38 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. Do you think this is a better bet?

Answer (score 1):

First, see what kind of file you have:

```
file plsToBed
```

This will print the kind of file (including details about the target architecture).

Next, there's no need to copy the file anywhere before trying to run it. If it's in a particular location and you have `cd` to that location, then simply:

```
./plsToBed
```

will execute it from the current directory.

You shouldn't have been able to copy to `/usr/local/bin` without being root (I hope you're not doing all this as root).

You don't want to add the name of the file itself to the `PATH` environment variable; the `PATH` is a list of *directories*, not files.